# Importing from oracle to mysql using csv

Tags: mysql, oracle, csv

I have a csv file (12 gb) which exported from oracle database,

formatted like

> 6436,,N,,,,,,,,,,,,04/01/1999,04/01/1999,352,1270,1270,406,406,1999,1,31/01/1999,0,88,0,A,11/12/2005,N,0,11/12/2005,,,,1270,1,0,,2974,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

As you see it has a lot of null values (mostly integer),
And when i import it to mysql database, It fills null values with zero

Like,

> 6436,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,04/01/1999,04/01/1999,1270,1270,406,406,1999,1,31,31/01/1999,88,0,A,11/12/2005,N,0,11/12/2005,0,0,0,1270,1,0,,2974,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,00/00/0000,0,,0,0

What is the real issue here?
Thanks.

Comment: because an sql null literally means "unknown value". csv doesn't have nulls, period. it has empty strings, which are NOT unknown values. they're strings of length zero. if you want those fields to become null in your table, you'll have to tell the db to do so at import time, e.g. `load ... set columnX=if(length(valueX) = 0) then null else valueX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out with helpful comment of @Marc B

I wrote something like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/data.csv' INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES
(columns with @)

SET
   column = IF(length(@column)= 0,null,@column),
   date = str_to_date(@date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```